# So, how will the Blackberry Playbook support android apps?

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-playbook

I've read a lot of vague things online about support of android apps on the Playbook, but am still unclear on the particulars.  Specifically, I was looking to find out:

1. How will users be able to purchase and install Android apps? (How can android developers make their apps available?)
2. Will the apps run exactly as they would on Android?  What will happen with things like OS variables, and Android imposed memory constraints?

Thanks

Comment: From what I've heard, it hasn't been announced how this will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until such a time as RIM releases support for the Playbook to actually run an Android APK, your questions will be unable to be answered accurately without a properly functioning crystal ball.

Comment: any chance you a projected date for that?  I have been able to find one...

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a chatroom.  Please stick to asking questions about problems you're having developing software.

Comment: Thought it might be of interest to android and blackberry devs; but I understand.  Sorry about that.